# android camera intent returns no data

Tags: java, android, camera

I have a problem with obtaining data from on the 'onActivityResult' method after taking a picture from the camera intent.

Here is my method which is calling camera Intent:

```
private void __initCamera() {

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/vault/images/";

    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
        dir = new File(path);
    }
    String[] content = dir.list();
    String fileName = (content.length + 1) + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(path, fileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("my_app", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);  
    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(i, 8765);
}
```

Here is my onActivityResult method:

returnCode: `-1(should be: 1, right?),`

exception:`java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: #Intent;action=inline-data;end`

data.toURI() : `#Intent;action=inline-data;end`

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int returnCode, Intent data) {

    try {

        Bitmap bitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(data.toURI()));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
        bitmap.recycle();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("TROLL", ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think you should call createnewfile, camera app will create file for you

Comment: I just tried it when i saw filenotfoundexception... both solutions(with create file/without) give same exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: #Intent;action=inline-data;end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(data.toURI()));
```

Should be this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

At least, that's how I normally retrieve images.  Also, I would recommend checking for the correct request code instead of using an all encompassing Exception there.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer only provides a way to obtain a thumbnail of image, not the full size one.
To get the full size image you should provide a uri where camera will store the image like this:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
```

Then in your `onActivityResult` you can use your saved uri to get the image:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mUri));
```

Here's the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).